# The nRF52 didn't detect the I2C address of the ultrasound sensor (RCWL9620) on the I2C bus

Tags: i2c, detect, nrf52

I'm using Segger as an IDE. I have an nRF52 with a mux I2C. The BLE detects the address of the mux, and I select the channel that is already connected. However, BLE detects the I2C ultrasound (RCWL9620) once but doesn't detect it for the second time.

The ultrasound sensor works in Arduino and STM platforms, but when I used it with the nRF platform, I encountered a problem in detecting its address. I already created a program that successfully detects the multiplexer (mux) and then selects the channel that is already connected to RCWL9620. However, when I check for the I2C address of the sensors, the program detects it once but not the second time. I have repeated the process multiple times, and each time, it only detects the address once and fails to do so the second time."